# Page not showing properly if i use $.mobile.changePage()

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have many html code like this

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">       
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">       
</div>
```

In a single html i have many pages.
Now if i go from one page1 to page2 like this

```
$.mobile.changePage("#page2", {transition : "slide"});
```

Then the browser shows me page2 then it shows me page1 for 3 seconds and then again it successfully come back to page2.

How to correct this issue?

Comment: @ghostCoder jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js

Comment: Are you testing with an android device?

Comment: Hi @codaniel Yes Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transitions in JQM 1.0.x were quite rough on some devices most notably android 1.x, 2.x . They have been much approved in JQM version 1.1-RC1. Try updating to JQM 1.1-RC1.

**UPDATE:** Please note that if the browser such as the one android uses cannot handle 3D transforms it will simply fallback to a fade transition.

Comment: I am testing it on Android 2.2.let me update and come back to u

Comment: It is working better on 1.1.0.But suppose if i move from page1 to page2 and then again i come back to page1 then it shows me some cached vales..How to deal with that?